# SQL UPDATE boolean from a db selecting a minium value of number WHERE boolean=false

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-select-db

I want to UPDATE my database from a previous selection. I mean I need to select the minium value of the register when the boolean=false and then change the value of the boolean of that record to true. They are all from the same table.

```
numberColumn    booleanColumn
     1                1                   
     2                1
     3                0
     4                0
```

Result need to be this:

```
numberColumn    booleanColumn
     1                1                   
     2                1
     3                1
     4                0
```

The statement im using is like this and there is probably an error on the syntax.

```
"UPDATE db(booleanColumn) SELECT MIN(numberColumn) FROM db WHERE boolean='0' SET boolean='1'"
```

Im feeling like I need to nest something like:

```
"UPDATE db(booleanColumn) 
SET boolean='1'
WHERE (SELECT MIN(numberColumn) WHERE boolean=0)"
```

but if not working also.
I dont know if you are getting the question or I need to express myself better. Thank you from now,

Comment: I am guessing that "mysql-select-db" implies "mysql".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do:

```
update db.table
    set boolean = 1
    where boolean = 0
    order by numberColumn
    limit 1;
```

Comment: It worked! Ty! the only change I made is that I didnt selected the table. So I changed db for db.table

update db.table
    set boolean = 1
    where boolean = 0
    order by numberColumn
    limit 1;

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can do this way

```
;with cte as  
(   
    select top(1) * from db
    where boolean = 0
   order by numberColumn
     )          
update cte set  boolean = 1
```